# Nest Table Inside Repeater & Connect 2 SQL Server tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Using SQL Server, I have created a Group details table & an Events table. When you add an event to the table, it is associated with a particular Group.

Below, I can display all group details using a repeater. However, I also want to display the events which are associated with each group.

Here is my Group details Repeater:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                            <asp:Repeater ID="rptAccordian" runat="server">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                                        <div class="panel-heading">
                                            <h3 class="panel-title">
                                                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse<%= getIndex() %>">
                                                    <%# Eval("Group_Name") %>
                                                </a>
                                            </h3>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- Get the current index-->
                                        <div id="collapse<%=getIndex()%>" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                            <div class="panel-body">
                                                <%# Eval("Group_Desc") %>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--then increment it for the next repeater element-->
                                    <% incrementIndex(); %>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
                        </div>
```

Code behind:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select * from Groups News ORDER BY Group_Id DESC";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            rptAccordian.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            rptAccordian.DataBind();
            con.Close();
```

This code below, displays events, but not Per Group:

```
<div class="panel-body" style="height: 400px; overflow-y: scroll;">
                        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand" EnableViewState="false">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <div>

                                    <table class="table table-striped">

                                        <tr>
                                            <th><%#Eval("Event_Title")%></th>
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Event Group ID</td>
                                            <td><%#Eval("Event_Cost") %></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Event Type</td>
                                            <td><%#Eval("Event_Type")  %></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Event ID</td>
                                            <td><%#Eval("Id")  %></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Cost</td>
                                            <td><%#Eval("Event_Cost")  %></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Description</td>
                                            <td><%#Eval("Event_Desc")  %></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Organiser</td>
                                            <td><%#Eval("Event_Organiser")  %></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Date</td>
                                            <td><%#Eval("Event_Date")  %></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Location</td>
                                            <td><%#Eval("Event_Location")  %></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Time</td>
                                            <td><%#Eval("Event_Start_Time")  %></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <br />
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                    </div>
```

Code Behind:

```
connR = new SqlConnection(connectionStringR);
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Events", connR);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);
    Repeater1.DataSource = dt;
    Repeater1.DataBind();
```

And here are my table structures:

Group table:

[image: group]

Events table:
[image: group1]

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Group_Events] (
[Id]               INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Group_Event_ID]   INT           NULL,
[Event_Type]       NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Event_Title]      NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Event_Cost]       FLOAT (53)    NULL,
[Event_Desc]       NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Event_Organiser]  NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Event_Date]       DATE          NULL,
[Event_Location]   NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Event_Start_Time] DATETIME      NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC));

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Groups] (
[Group_Id]   INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Group_Name] NVARCHAR (50)   NULL,
[Group_Desc] NVARCHAR (1000) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Group_Id] ASC));
```

Group_Id (PK) is the FK Group_Event_ID in the Events table.

I'm not sure how to nest the Events table which I have created above, into my rptAccordian for Groups.

I've tried with the below code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptAccordian" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                                        <div class="panel-heading">
                                            <h3 class="panel-title">
                                                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse<%= getIndex() %>">
                                                    <%# Eval("Group_Name") %>
                                                </a>
                                            </h3>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- Get the current index-->
                                        <div id="collapse<%=getIndex()%>" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                            <div class="panel-body">
                                                <p>
                                                    <%# Eval("Group_Desc") %>
                                                </p>

                                                <table id="tblGroupEvents" class="table table-bordered">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th><%# Eval("Event_Title") %></th>
                                                        <td></td>
                                                        <td></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--then increment it for the next repeater element-->
                                    <% incrementIndex(); %>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
```

Code behind:

```
 private void BindRepeater()
{
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BallinoraDBConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            //ORDER BY DATE
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from Groups News ORDER BY Group_Id DESC";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            rptAccordian.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            rptAccordian.DataBind();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}

protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    Table table = e.Item.FindControl("tblGroupEvents") as Table;

    string Group_Id = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Group_Id").ToString();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Group_Events WHERE (Group_Event_ID = '" + Group_Id + "'", con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     sda.Fill(dt);

    table.DataBind();
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Additional information: DataBinding: 'System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal' does not contain a property with the name 'Event_Title'.

Any ideas?

Comment: How many time are you going to post the exact same question? None of them so far have really had ddl and sample data. Pictures of data like this do not let others write queries. Since you don't know how many columns you are going to have a repeater is not the right tool for the job here. You need to have a dynamic number of columns. You need to first get the data the way you want it, then you can worry about how you present it. Given the dynamic nature of what you are trying to do it is going to take some coding, a repeater can't handle a dynamic number of columns like this.

Comment: @SeanLange DDL above

Comment: How about some sample data? And what happened with the pictures? This is nearly the exact same thing but now the tables and data have changed. The requirements seem to be exactly the same though.

Comment: @SeanLange As for sample data, it can be just any text, when inserting I just used text boxes & dropdown's to enter the values. Will I post that insert code? I managed to get a solution for the images, but I'm having trouble adapting that code from displaying images in a DataList, to displaying Text in table rows

Comment: @SeanLange I have tried to adapt the images solution I found previously, and I have posted my attempt above. That solution used "OnItemDataBound" so I have added code to that above to see if that works